# Oracle union clarification needed for query with union join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

below is just an example which resembles to union query which i am running. i have a question around alias table xyz_1. How oracle takes care of such alias table created along with union? does oracle run both statements in different SGA and hence they are not visible to each other?

```
select * from
abc, (select a from xyx where c='yes') xyz_1
where
abc.col_1 = xyz_1.col_1
union
select * from
abc, (select a from xyx where c='no') xyz_1
where
abc.col_1 = xyz_1.col_1
```

Comment: Is this working for you? I wasn't aware Oracle allowed you to assign aliases in the unioned queries. Normally you only assign the aliases in the first query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNION is a set operator whose function is to combine the results of two queries. Both queries are executed independently, else it is ok to use the same table alias in both queries, as you would usually do in a subquery for example. The only constraint when using UNION is that the two queries must return the same number of fields, and with similar datatypes (considering that implicit conversion may happen).

The [the Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) do not mention any restriction on aliasing within subqueries :

> You can combine multiple queries using the set operators UNION, UNION ALL, INTERSECT, and MINUS. All set operators have equal precedence. If a SQL statement contains multiple set operators, then Oracle Database evaluates them from the left to right unless parentheses explicitly specify another order.

Comment: Thanks for answering.